# coffeescript scope of the @ keyword in class

Tags: coffeescript, scoping

I have some problems with the scope of the `@` keyword in an anonymous function

(this is not what's happening but I need it for my example)

```
createArray = (fun) -> fun()
```

this is the example class

```
class Example
    stuff: []
    otherStuff: createArray ->
        @stuff
```

the `@` points to `window` (I presume). So I looked into this and remembered the [fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) to create a generator function.

I tried this

```
class Example
    stuff: []
    otherStuff: createArray =>
        @stuff
```

but it didn't even compile to a `function(_this) { ...}(this)`. So I started trying to wrap in generators everything

```
class Example
    stuff: []
    otherStuff: =>
        createArray ->
            @stuff

...
   otherStuff: =>
       stuff = @stuff
       createArray ->
           stuff
...
   otherStuff: ((stuff) ->
       createArray ->
           stuff
   )(@stuff) #this is the one that upsets me the most because it compiles to Example.stuff and not to Example.prototype.stuff
```

but none of these are working.

Before switching to a simple `function` instead of `class`, is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

```
otherStuff: createArray ->
    @stuff
```

This is run *at class definition time*, not when you execute `otherStuff()`. At that time there is no `this` (`@`), because no object has yet been instantiated. Essentially this is doing:

```
Example.prototype.otherStuff = (function () { return this.stuff; })();
// which boils down to:
Example.prototype.otherStuff = this.stuff;
```

Obviously, `this` has nothing to do with an instance of `Example` at this point.

If you want `@` to refer to the current instance of `Example`, you need to defer your function execution until you have an instance and call `otherStuff`:

```
otherStuff: ->
    createArray ->
        @stuff
```

Here now the inner function will lose its context, and you need to fat-arrow bind it:

```
otherStuff: ->
    createArray =>
        @stuff
```

Comment: I want the result of `createArray` bound to `@otherStuff` at creation time of the class, that's why I was trying to create a self executing function.

Comment: Well, at the creation time of the class, there's no `this` yet... so... that's somewhat impossible.